# Condition WhereIn Id Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I try to make a condition and check if the activite_licencie_id is in else if the id is different from the whereIn Condition it's false

Actually however the id i get from activite_licencie_id i get "Good" so the condition doesn't work because somethings i select the id = 2 who is not In the ids from the whereIn Condition. someone know how i could achieve that ? thanks a lot in advance

```
$activite_licencie_id = $request->activite_licencie_id; // id = 2
if (ActiviteLicencie::where('id' , $activite_licencie_id)->whereIn('id' , [1 , 14 , 15 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 36 , 51] ) == true){
    $good ='good';
    dd($good);
}else{
     $bad = 'bad';
     dd($bad);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of querying the table when you're forcing your results based on the second whereIn condition? Just check if the second array holds the license id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already certain that the model ids you're passing to the `whereIn` clause exist, then why not just use `in_array`?

```
$activite_licencie_id = $request->activite_licencie_id;
$ids = [1 , 14 , 15 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 36 , 51];

if (in_array($activite_licencie_id, $ids)) {
    dd('good');
} else {
    dd('bad');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than comparing to true, you should compare the `count()` of the result.

Change `== true` to `->count() >= 0`

```
 $activite_licencie_id = $request->activite_licencie_id; // id = 2



  if (ActiviteLicencie::where('id' , $activite_licencie_id)->whereIn('id' , [1 , 14 , 15 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 36 , 51] )->count() >=0){

      $good ='good';
      dd($good);
  }else{

      $bad = 'bad';
      dd($bad);
  }
```